# Selenium click on next button

Tags: python, selenium

How can i get selenium to click on the next button from the HTML code below?

```
<span class="action-btn" data-bind="visible: viewModel.page() < viewModel.pages(), click: viewModel.changePage(+1);">&gt;</span>
```

Initially I wrote:

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_class_name('action-btn')
elm.click()
time.sleep(4)
```

But I noticed that in the website, there are other `buttons` with similar names as well. Such as `action-btn customize` and `action-btn right`

With my current code, its basically just clicking on `action-btn customize` and my guess is because this button name comes before the code that I intended to click on.

How should I be writing my code instead?

**Update**

Here is a screen shot of the frame. The yellow highlight is what I am trying to click on.

[image: image of HTML code]

Comment: Are there any other features which distinguish this button like its parent or something?

Comment: One cannot say for sure with this snippet of HTML. If the page is something that you made yourself, simply add an ID to the buttons that interest you.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the frame with the button that I want to click on. Hope this is helpful!

Comment: You can use xpaths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot it seems the `action-btn` you want to click is the last one in `pager` class.

And, if you have only one `div` element with class `pager`, you could select all `action-btn` inside it and get the last one:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.pager span.action-btn:last-of-type");
```

Here are more details about [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alast-of-type) selector:

> The `:last-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents the last sibling with the given element name in the list of children of its parent element.

Comment: Some comments for the downvote would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @jakewong. I am glad that the solution worked for you. But someone did downvote and that even without an explanation.